# SharePoint 2007 - Shared Services Provider - Application Pool has been disabled

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We are using SharePoint 2007. It was installed and set up before I started working here. Now I am the lucky one to take care of the administration.

**I need help to figure out why I cannot access my Shared Services Provider (SSP) website to do administration.** When I try to access the SSP website through a browser I receive either a 503 Service Not Available, or 404 Page Cannot Be Found HTTP Error.

The 3 event viewer messages below leads me to believe the custom service accounts I have might need the password updated. I have a few questions from the given information though...

**Question set #1:** If I need to update the password for the service account, then how can I currently access Central Administration and other areas having this service account assigned? Shouldn't I also get an error for those areas?

**Question set #2:** If updating the password is needed, what are the steps involved in doing so? And, how will it affect the use of SP? Is it best to do this on off hours?

> Below are the two warnings and one error I receive in the Event Viewer/System Log of the web server when trying to start the SSP App Pool (in order of occurrence).
>
> **Warning #1:** The identity of application pool [App Pool Name] is invalid. The user name or password that is specified for the identity may be incorrect, or the user may not have batch logon rights. If the identity is not corrected, the application pool will be disabled when the application pool receives its first request.  If batch logon rights are causing the problem, the identity in the IIS configuration store must be changed after rights have been granted before Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) can retry the logon. If the identity remains invalid after the first request for the application pool is processed, the application pool will be disabled. The data field contains the error number. **Event ID: 5021**
>
> **Warning #2:** Application pool [App Pool Name] has been disabled. Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) did not create a worker process to serve the application pool because the application pool identity is invalid. **Event ID: 5057**
>
> **Error:** Application pool [App Pool Name] has been disabled. Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) encountered a failure when it started a worker process to serve the application pool. **Event Id: 5059**

Thank you for any help to resolve my issue!

Answer (score 1):

their are stsadm commands to change the password or update the services accounts for web application / SSP/ Central admin. Once you change it, you can access it.

**SSP**

- Update the password for the account that is used by every Shared
  Services Provider (SSP) on the server farm. To do this, type the
  following line at a command prompt on every server on the server
  farm, and then press Enter:

  stsadm.exe -o editssp -title SharedServicesProviderName -ssplogin DomainName\UserName -ssppassword NewPassword

**Central Admin**

Update the password for the account that is used by the Central Administration application pool. To do this, follow these steps:

- On all servers in the server farm, open a command prompt, type the
  following line, and then press Enter: `cd %commonprogramfiles%\Microsoft Shared\Web server extensions\12\Bin`
- Do one of the following:

On the server that hosts the Central Administration website, type the following line at the command prompt, and then press Enter:

```
stsadm -o updatefarmcredentials -userlogin DomainName\UserName -password NewPassword
```

On all other servers in the server farm, type the following line at the command prompt, and then press Enter:

```
stsadm -o updatefarmcredentials -userlogin DomainName\UserName -password NewPassword -local
```

- Restart Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0. To do this, type the
  following line at the command prompt, and then press Enter:

  iisreset /noforce

**Web Application AppPool**

- Update the password for the application pool account that is used by
  web applications on the server farm. To do this, type the following
  line at a command prompt on every server on the server farm, and then
  press Enter:

  stsadm -o updateaccountpassword -userlogin DomainName\UserName -password NewPassword -noadmin

for more options check this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934838